# Opening a telnet session using TCL in windows

Tags: windows, tcl, telnet

Is it possible to connect to a specific ip and host over telnet using TCL, in windows? I can't seem to find any information about this, there are some info for Linux but none for Windows.

EDIT:
OK, I got it working. Initially I had this code:

```
set s [socket $ip_address $host]
puts $s "hi there"
```

but when running this code, nothing would actually be transmitted to the server. Only after I ran

```
flush $s
```

would the text be transmitted. I had thought that the puts command would do this automatically, I'm not sure why I have to use the flush command.

Comment: Is Telnet not just a raw TCP connection? Or does it have other boilerplate?

Comment: Yes, a raw TCP connection will work fine.  There should not be any difference between windows and linux setting up the connection.

Comment: Yes, I tried the socket command used for TCP and it worked, but still don't understand why the flush command is needed, updated the question accordingly.

Comment: Your question is misleading. telnet is a program and I don't think that you want to execute and control telnet.exe from within tcl, right? Please edit your question...

Comment: To no longer need the "flush" command, configure your socket to use no buffering:  "fconfigure $s -buffering none"  Otherwise it buffers until it has a full line to send, and your example had no line completion character. (e.g., "\n")

Comment: @ErikJohnson Sockets are _fully_ buffered by default, not line buffered, so Tcl waits until it's got a few kilobytes of output to send. Not that it matters very much in practice; you still want to `fconfigure` the `-buffering` the same.

Comment: @DonalFellows Of course they are, and I normally know that. :)  I've just been working with a script using stdout, which *is* line buffered, and crossed my mental wires.  Thanks for the catch.